# Is it possible to create a function which performs a warp of an image given target scalings of pixels?

Tags: math, image-processing, deep-learning, neural-network

Background: my goal is to create a conditional generative model that takes in an image of something with regular properties, like text from a PDF, that has been distorted in some way and returns some sort of data describing a warp which can be applied to normalize it (its loss would be based on SSIM to the ground truth).

To start off, I'm thinking this question might be better suited to the Math StackExchange.

Based on this, the first type of data potentially describing a warp that came to mind would be a map where each pixel is assigned a value indicating the stretch that area should receive in the output image. It would use some form of interpolation, of course. Here are some characteristics that this warp map should have:

- It should actually scale parts of the image. Specifically, the area of some region in the output image should approach the mean scaling value of the pixels in that region times its area in the input image w.r.t. the number of pixels in said region.
- It should be continuous, meaning if some values in the warp map are changed slightly, the output image changes only slightly
- Application should be distributive over translation and rotation.
- Results should be roughly preserved under dimension changes. If we have a high resolution image and a high resolution warp map, then downscaling both and applying the low res warp map to the low res image should have nearly the same results as applying the high resolution warp map to the high resolution image.

I'm wondering:

1. If such a transformation is even possible, and if so
2. How it could be implemented (I don't need working code, just a description of how an algorithm could work that applies a warp map in this way)

I would also greatly appreciate other suggestions on how to accomplish something similar to this (i.e. a method to allow generalized warping from a neural net)

Comment: If you're talking about the sort of warped text used in a CAPTCHA, the whole point of warping the text is to make it difficult for you to unwarp it programmatically. So it's going to be very difficult by design. That being said, it is apparently [possible](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-algorithm-busts-captcha-with-99-8-percent-accuracy/). Good luck.

Comment: @JohnWu it would be on a larger scale, with more text and less significant warping. The work of figuring out how it was warped would be figured out by the CNN. My question is purely about the implementation of an algorithm which unwarps and image given a map of how big each region should be in the image.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [image registration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration). You are looking to do non-rigid registration, which is much more expensive computationally than rigid or affine registration. One of the more successful methods involve a grid of points on one image, the registration algorithm then finds how to move these points to match it up to the second image. The points are control points for a [thin-plate spline interpolation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_plate_spline).

Many implementations exist. I hope the keywords above help you find some of them.